# WP_Query 500 internal error / Scope between php files

Tags: php, scope, wordpress

OK - here's the problem: I perform a new WP_Query on one php file:

```
$args = array(  'post_type' => ... );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

This gives me a set of all relevant posts. I then do some hierarchical logic stuff and I ask the user to make a selection which I then send back to the server (using _POST).

In a second php file where I receive the user selection, I basically need to access the same set of posts. However, when I try to an identical WP_Query I get a 500 internal server error... I am probably missing something really simple here. Any ideas why I cannot perform another query? And/or as a workaround, is it possible to still access the query results from the first file (e.g. by saving the info I need into some kind of global multidimensional array?) if that's even possible

Excuse my ignorance, first time web developer... Thanks

Comment: How are you calling this file? my bet is that the `WP_Query` object isn't available to you because you've made a custom php file like, `my-custom-file.php` which doesn't follow WP's developer guidelines and therefore isn't doing `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` to retrieve those assets.

Comment: Oh that must be it! It's called post.php :) So what are my naming options for such a file then? Its purpose is basically to export part of the selected data. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: If you want access to the core wordpress funtions, then it's just `require('./wp-blog-header.php');`. Adjust that line to be the proper path to that file, and then you can use WP functions outside of the core.

Comment: OK - it worked. Thanks! I am sure it's not the cleanest way to do it though with: require './../../../wp-blog-header.php'; I have plenty of reading to do on the guidelines I suppose to do things properly..